Leading term of difference of two polynomials defined recursively
Define two polynomial sequences  by
$$
\cases{P_0(x)=x\\
Q_0(x)=1}\\
\cases{P_{n+1}(x)=P_n(x-1)Q_n(x+1)\\
Q_{n+1}(x)=P_n(x+1)Q_n(x-1)}
$$
Is it true that the leading term of $ Q_n(x) - P_n(x) $ is $ 2^n \cdot (n-1)! \cdot x^n $ for all $ n \geq 1 $? Thanks.

Verification for $ n = 1 $ to $ 10 $.
var('x')
P = [x]
Q = [1]

# Compute P_n and Q_n for n=1 to 10
for n in range(10):
    P_next = P[n].subs(x=x-1) * Q[n].subs(x=x+1)
    Q_next = P[n].subs(x=x+1) * Q[n].subs(x=x-1)
    P.append(P_next)
    Q.append(Q_next)

for n in range(1, 11):
    LHS = (Q[n] - P[n]).expand().leading_coefficient(x)
    RHS = 2**n * factorial(n-1)
    print(f"n={n}: {bool(LHS == RHS)}")

